# Is "top student in xxx module" worth writing on a grad school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, awards

So I'm currently a university undergrad, and I was notified that I was among the top students (out of ~200) in one of the modules that I took, let's call it CS4321. I'm also thinking of applying to grad school in an area that is related to the content of CS4321. Would this achievement be worth writing on my resume or somewhere in my application, or is it too minor to be of use?

Comment: For admission to U.S. graduate programs, this is something that it would probably be best to have mentioned in a letter of recommendation by the module's teacher who, given your performance in the module, one would expect to be one of your letter writers. However, this might not be appropriate in your situation, so it would probably help to include your university's country and the countries where you are applying for graduate work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put it on your resume as 'top student in CS4321'.

This has two reasons. First of all, it implies you were **the** number one top student in the course. Which is not the case, as you say in the question. Second, even if you'd write something like 'one of the top students in CS4321', this is not an official definition so this can mean anything or nothing at all. Top 1%? Top 10? 90th percentile? All different implications.

Like Dave L Renfro suggest in a comment, let the course instructor mention this in their letter of recommendation. Because it is of course good and notable to be a top students in a 200 person class.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach probably varies by country. Here in the UK, you would typically get a score for each module, and 70%+ is considered a first-class grade. I'd rather hear about your score for the module rather than the percentile against your peers.

e.g. 'I scored 96% in my dynamics module' would look good when applying to grad school to study dynamics. I would prefer to see that rather than a comparison against the other students.